# How to use browser's back button to get previous searche page

Tags: reactjs

I have a search page which redirects to `search results page` using the below logic

```
 <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="search ..." className="osLight english" name="query"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          {
            this.state.searchProperties.length > 0 &&
            <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/search',
              results: this.state.searchProperties
            }} />
          }
```

now... in the search result I can click and go to one of the products

```
const properties = this.props.location.results;
<div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 arabic-english">
     <Link className="card" to={{
         pathname: "/" + property.property_id,
         property: property
     }}
     >
...
    </Link>
</div>
```

but now when I press back in the browser I go to an empty `search result page`, how can I maintain the search result state in order to be viewed when I press back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Exorcismus you can use history object and query string to get search results.

Please find '[React JS - using back button to get previous searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51698525/react-js-using-back-button-to-get-previous-searches)' as link which can help you out.

Kindly revert if this does not help.

Comment: I don't have a query in my case ... my result has already been generated in an earlier step.

Comment: Can prevState or prevProps help us out to get search keyword or results on ComponentDidUpdate hook?

Comment: I can pass the query instead of the search result direct ... but still am having the problem when navigating from a product page to the search result again